# Policy improvement theorem in reinforcement learning, how to prove it?

Tags: proof-explanation, machine-learning

I'm watching the [deep mind course of david Silver on reinforcement learning, lecture 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nd1-UUMVfz4&list=PLqYmG7hTraZDM-OYHWgPebj2MfCFzFObQ&index=3).

At around 46:00, he gives a proof for the policy improvement theorem, stated below.
However, I'm struggling with the most essential step of the proof.

I won't define everything in the theorem, the elements are defined in the video serie.
Here's the theorem.

> **Given a policy $\pi$,**
>
> **evaluate the policy** $\pi : v_\pi(s) = \mathbb{E}[R_{t+1}+\gamma R_{t+2} + ... | S_t = s] $
>
> **Define a new policy that choose the direct most rewarding action for every state :**
>
> $\pi'(s) = argmax_{a \in A}  \quad q_{\pi}(s,a)$
>
> **with $q_{\pi}$ the state-action value function, computed using $v_\pi$.**
>
> **By repeating those two steps iteratively, the policy will converge toward the optimal policy.**

***The proof :***

The proof starts by showing that the state-action value when following $\pi'(s)$ for our next action is superior to the state value when following policy $\pi(s)$ :

by definition of the  $\pi'(s)$ policy :

$q_{\pi}(s,\pi'(s)) =  \max_{a \in A}  \quad q_{\pi}(s,a) \geq q_{\pi}(s,\pi(s)) = v_{\pi}(s)$

this makes sense to me, what doesn't is the following line of the proof :

$v_{\pi}(s) \leq q_{\pi}(s,\pi'(s)) = \mathbb{E_{\pi'}}[R_{t+1} + \gamma v_{\pi}(S_{t+1})|S_t = s] $

This looks like the Bellman equation for the ****state value** function** :

$v_{\pi}(s) = \mathbb{E_{\pi}}[R_{t+1} + \gamma v_{\pi}(S_{t+1})|S_t = s]$

But we should apply the Bellman equation for the **state-action value function** :

$q_{\pi}(s,a) = \mathbb{E_{\pi}}[R_{t+1} + \gamma q_{\pi}(S_{t+1},A_{t+1})|S_t = s, A_t = a] $

By applying this equation to $q_{\pi}(s,\pi'(s))$ we get :

$q_{\pi}(s,\pi'(s)) = \mathbb{E_{\pi}}[R_{t+1} + \gamma q_{\pi}(S_{t+1},A_{t+1})|S_t = s, A_t = \pi'(s)] $

So here is my question :

**How do we show that**

$\mathbb{E_{\pi}}[R_{t+1} + \gamma q_{\pi}(S_{t+1},A_{t+1})|S_t = s, A_t = \pi'(s)] =  \mathbb{E_{\pi'}}[R_{t+1} + \gamma v_{\pi}(S_{t+1})|S_t = s]$ **?**

Those are two very different expressions and I can't connect the dots ! Your help would be very appreciated !